# What is name of the red eyed rabbit or hare, found in Himalayan region?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Is it Rabbit or Hare?

[image]
[image]

The eyes are red in colour.

These animals are habitat of Himalaya.

The pictures are taken in Dowhill Park, Kurseong, West Bengal, India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit underwhelmingly, those are Himalayan Rabbits.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himalayan_rabbit

The pure white fur and red eyes are usually a sign of albinos, but in this case it's actually a trait of the entire species.

> [They] can only produce eumelanin under a certain temperature and they cannot produce pheomelanin at all.

Comment: Thank you for the identification. It's strange that the Wikipedia page doesn't have the classification. I have a question though, the article is saying a breed of rabbit. What does it mean? A species of rabbit?

Comment: It means a species of rabbit, yes. Of the genus Oryctolagus.